# algorithm to find the shortest subarray with distinct values

Tags: algorithm

Given an array A, find a shortest subarray A[i : j ] such that each distinct value present in A is also present in the subarray.

The question is not for a homework. It's a practice problem from a chapter on Hash tables. I am not looking for the code. Just looking for the algorithm or hints.

Comment: `not for a homework. It's a practice problem from a chapter` Doesn't it sound like **it's the very same thing**?

Comment: @DerGolem Not really. One is imposed by someone else, the other is self-learning. The question is only looking for algorithm pointers rather than having the answer spoon fed, too.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447561/find-shortest-subarray-containing-all-elements) question. If you do not know the distinct elements, you would have a ``O(n * log(n))`` solution, otherwise it even is ``O(n)``

Comment: It a self-imposed homework.

Comment: it's _homework_, it's not for _assessment_.  the obvious answer is to use a hash table :)

Comment: Distinct elements could be determined at `O(n)`, so `O(n * log(n))` is doubtful. But if looking at, say, {0 1 0 2 0 0 0 1 2 0} example, I'm not sure if there exists `O(n)` solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use a hash table to maintain a count of each type of element in the string.

when you find a new type of element
discard all previous answers and start trimming the start of the substring,
when you can trim it no more without having zero of one type of element
remember the substring if it's the shortest yet found  and then start looking for another element to replace the one you are about to loose or to find a new element not previously seen as above.

When you hit the end of the string you are done.

If your hash is any good, this should be O(n)

Comment: Suppose I have the series of elements as aaabbbccccaaabc so we have two windows,  one is the A[2:6]  and A[12:14].  When we scan past the first 2:6, although we do not know that all are done, but we can not discard the newer a's or b's. Since it could have been cba at the end. Will this method work for such cases?  More doubts.. If we hit a new element, we discard the previous answers, did not get that. The newer element will be any way added into the Hashed set.

Comment: The window counts up and down keeping a tally of the total number of each letter in the window. separately a record of the coordinates of shortest complete window yet found.  why to discard: if we find a 'd' at position 15 any the answers that had only {a,b,c} is worthless, but we can tack the d onto the end of the most recent complete window found howevewe 12:16 has the full set,

Answer (score 1):

1- Maintain a hash table element->count

2- Traverse array from begin to end, incrementing the element count. Whenever an element count is changed from 0 to 1, record it's index in a variable , say index_0_1. In the end index_0_1 will have end index of a potential ans.

3- Traverse array from begin to index_0_1, decrementing the element count. Stop, whenever an element count is changed from 1 to 0, record it's index in a variable, say index_1_0. subarray A[index_1_0 : index_0_1] is a potential ans, record it.

4- Traverse from index_0_1 towards end, incrementing the element count and stop whenever you find element A[index_1_0]. Update index_0_1 with current index.

5- Traverse from index_1_0+1 to  index_0_1, decrementing the element count. Stop whenever an element count is changed from 1 to 0. This is new index_1_0. If subarray A[index_1_0: index_0_1] is smaller than previous ans, update it and continue with steps 4 and step 5, until whole array have been traversed.